# Angular component - actualize data every time view is shown

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I'm using ionic. I have a really basic question on actualizing data in component.
I fetch data in components `ngOnInit` method over httpservice.
This is only done once but it should be done every time this component is shown in view.
What is the appropriated way to do this.

```
ngOnInit()
    myService.getData().subscribe(response => {
   
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Comment: Couple of quick questions, can you please share the implementation of `getData` method of `MyService`? and are you using Ionic framework (ionic has its own lifecycle hook eg. like `ionViewDidEnter()`?

Comment: Thanks Parkar, I use ionic und that did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call a method in `subscribe`.

```
ngOnInit() {
    myService.getData().subscribe(response => {
        this.someMethod(response);   // Add this line.
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}

someMethod = (response) => {
  // Write your logic here that you have to do after you fetched your data.
}
```

Comment: I think original question was `myService.getData`/`ngOnInit`, is not getting called when user enter second time on the page.

Comment: Not sure, how it could help to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic `ngOnInit` won't call when the page is revisited. The reason is Ionic doesn't remove the components from the DOM once they are visited.

So Ionic does follow different sets of lifecycle hooks. You have to call `ionViewDidEnter` hook to call something on component init.

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    myService.getData().subscribe(response => {
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```